# Distinct cumulative monthly counts of users

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get **cumulative** counts of users and AUM by month. However, a user can have multiple goals, which correspond to accounts, and accounts can have multiple positions.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f3c59/2

As you can see, this doesn't work because user 1 is in 2/1/18 with 300 AUM and then again counts in 3/1/18 with 400 AUM. So cumulatively, we are saying there are 3 users (instead of 3 goals), when there are actually only 2 users.

Is there a way to present this independent of monthly grouping? So 2/1/18 there are 2 clients with 500 AUM, and 3/1/18 there are still 2 clients but with 900 AUM?

Expected output:

```
month   users   AUM
2/1/18  2       500 
3/1/18  2       900
```

Comment: There's a lot of tables in that fiddle! Could you possibly simplify the queries, or provide an entity relationship diagram rather than having every reader try to reverse-engineer your objective? For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm not following how there are 2 clients in march? I only see a single record for march in the accounts table.I guess I don't nderstand your table structure, or what you are tring to do.

Comment: @JNevill Sorry expected output is supposed to be cumulative!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Here 2 `users` have 5 `goals` (user 1 with 4 goals, user 2 with 1 goal), that correspond to 5 `accounts` (user 1 with 2 "current" accounts in 2 different months, user 2 with 1 "current" account), that have 7 `positions` (user 1 with 6 positions, user 2 with one 400$ position).

Comment: @user8834780   are you sure that month 3 has two users ? I only see one user (user1) in the accounts table from your sample data, so it should be resulted 400 AUM, with one user. Also, I don't see the purpose of joining the goals here since you don't use its values !!

Comment: @iSR5 month 3 has 3 users CUMULATIVELY- 2 users is month 2, and 1 user (which is already in month 2) in month 3. 400 AUM for month 3 is correct but need to add the 500 from month 2 since I am asking for it to be CUMULATIVE. `Accounts` doesnt have `user_id` so we need the `goals` table for that - it was an oversight on my part sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have a solution for you that is working but it's very, very slow!!

```
select distinct date_trunc('month', a.date),
       (select count(distinct g.user_id) 
          from goals g 
            join accounts ac on ac.goal_id = g.id 
          where date_trunc('month', ac.date) <= date_trunc('month', a.date) 
           and ac.status = 'current'),
       (select sum(p.amount) 
          from positions p 
            join accounts acc on acc.id = p.account_id 
          where date_trunc('month', acc.date) <= date_trunc('month', a.date) 
            and acc.status='current')
from accounts a
where a.status = 'current'
```

I really can not see a way to do this without subqueries. In fact I think, that your data model is flawed. It took me a lot of time to get the relations right and after some time I realised, that you do not even need the "goals" and "users" tables for your purpose.

I actually have no good clue, how to improve your data model without knowing the whole database structure. My first step would be to store a separate value in your "accounts" table, which indicates the time slot, where the positions have to be summed up. I also thought about moving the "date" value to a separate table, but then again I don't know the whole database - so these are just simple ideas.

Comment: No problem! I updated my answer to make it work with the "goals" table. This one contains the "user_id" considering the data model. That extra join doesn't slow it down very much. The subqueries are much worse ;-)

Comment: @user8834780 if this works for you, then you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got what you need (kinda!)

IF I've got it right, the correct answer on the sample will be :

```
|                month | users | amount |
|----------------------|-------|--------|
| 2018-02-01T00:00:00Z |     2 |    500 |
| 2018-03-01T00:00:00Z |     3 |    900 |
```

there will be 1 user in month 3, and another 2 cumulative users from month 2 (previous month).

the user that in month 3 has $400, so when we add the previous month amount to it it'll be $900 ( 400 + 500) ...

if this is what you're looking for, 
then this is the query for it :

```
SELECT 
      month, 
      SUM(users) OVER(ORDER BY month ASC) AS users, 
      SUM(AUM) OVER(ORDER BY month ASC) AS amount
FROM (
select 
      date_trunc('month',date) as month, 
      count(distinct u.id) users, 
      sum(amount) AUM
from users u
join goals g on u.id=g.user_id
join accounts s on g.id=s.goal_id
join positions p on s.id=p.account_id
where status='current'
group by 1
) D
```

I hope this is what you're seeking!

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f3c59/8)

Comment: month 3 should have 2 users (as in my expected output) since user 1 appears in both month 2 and month 3 but it is just 1 user